# Could not autowire field from spring boot project to spring mvc project

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, autowired

I have two projects and I want autowire one interface from first to second. first project is a spring boot project but the second is not and is a spring mvc project.
there are three classes in second project to configure in the module configuration called "ProjectConfiguration" , "ProjectInitializer" , "ProjectListener".  I have added both interface and implementation of the interface dependencies to the second project's pom file and also path of the first project to ProjectConfiguration @ComponentScan. but when deploying the second project to tomcat it gives the exception:

The class in second project I'm autowiring in. ISampleResource is a interface in first project.

@Autowired
    ISampleResource sampleResource;

Stack Trace:

```
 Could not autowire field sampleResource: 
 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sample': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: ;
 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sample': 
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Could not autowire field: 
; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
 No qualifying bean of type 
found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. 
Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

ProjectListener Class:

```
public class ProjectListener implements ServletContextListener {

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        Security.addProvider(new FlexiCoreProvider());
        Security.addProvider(new FlexiECProvider());
        javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            public boolean verify(String s, SSLSession sslSession) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        System.out.println("Shutting down!");
    }
}
```

ProjectInitializer Class:

```
public class ProjectInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { ProjectConfiguration.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
        servletContext.addListener(new SMSContextListener());

    }
}
```

Comment: what is the full exception, what bean cannot be found?

Comment: sampleResource, I edited the question. @DarrenForsythe